# SQL Server - Select last 12 months including months without records

Tags: sql-server

I need to create reports using Select SQL's for SQLServer for last 12 months of count from a table. So far Iam able to create the following using various Stackoverflow answers. But, it does not get me the output with months without data.
        The following are couple of links that have helped me this far:
 [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8484078a-963f-4465-8045-c3a5418ac1b9/query-to-return-rolling-12-month-totals?forum=transactsql)

```
 (I apologize for any indentation errors(I've tried Ctl+K))
```

The table has many columns, but the one of interest for me to get the count is `lastupdatetimestamp`.

```
;WITH CTE_DatesTable
   AS 
(
 SELECT CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as datetime) AS lastupdatetimestamp
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DATEADD(m, -1, lastupdatetimestamp)
 FROM CTE_DatesTable
 WHERE DATEADD(m, -1, lastupdatetimestamp) > DATEADD(m, -12,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
)
SELECT [MONTH] ,
     [LAST_12_MONTHS]
FROM (  
SELECT MONTH(lastupdatetimestamp) AS   MonthNumber,
   DATENAME(MONTH,lastupdatetimestamp) AS [MONTH], 
   COUNT(*) AS [LAST_12_MONTHS]
 FROM FILES 
 GROUP BY MONTH(lastupdatetimestamp), 
    DATENAME(MONTH,lastupdatetimestamp)
    ) AS Data
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
  (
        SELECT YEAR(lastupdatetimestamp) AS YearNumber
              ,MONTH(lastupdatetimestamp) AS MonthNumber
        FROM CTE_DatesTable
    ) AS DateTable
ON Data.MonthNumber = DateTable.MonthNumber 
ORDER BY DateTable.MonthNumber DESC
```

This outputs:

```
| MONTH     | LAST_12_MONTHS |
|-----------|--------------- |
|   (null)  |   (null)       |
|   (null)  |   (null)       |
|   (null)  |   (null)       |
|   (null)  |   (null)       |
|   (null)  |   (null)       |
|   (null)  |   (null)       |
|   June    |   45           |
|   May     |   23           |
|   (null)  |   (null)       |
|   (null)  |   (null)       |
|   (null)  |   (null)       |
|   (null)  |   (null)       |
```

Required output:

```
| MONTH     | LAST_12_MONTHS |
|-----------|--------------- |
|   July    |   46           |
|   Aug     |   56           |
|   Sep     |   45           |
|   Oct     |   45           |
|   Nov     |   44           |
|   Dec     |   87           |
|   Jan     |   6            |
|   Feb     |   56           |
|   March   |   664          |
|   April   |   56           |
|   May     |   23           |
|   June    |   45           |
```

There are couple of issues with what i have so far :

1. The months without data are coming as 'null'
2. Iam getting calender months, instead of last 12 months.

   Any help is highly appreciated.

   Thank you

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Could you post your current output?

Comment: It seems like you just need a month table to join with.  Then you can do an ISNULL(thecount, 0).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea of one solution :

```
DECLARE @Now AS DATE = GETDATE()
;WITH LastTwelveMonth AS (
      SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@Now)-1), @Now),101) AS Date_Value
      UNION ALL
      SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, Date_Value))-1), @Now),101) AS Date_Value
      FROM LastTwelveMonth
), ValuesForMonth AS (
      SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(lastupdatetimestamp)-1), lastupdatetimestamp),101) AS DateForData, SUM(DataToCount) OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH(lastupdatetimestamp), YEAR(lastupdatetimestamp)) AS DataCounted
      FROM FILES
)
SELECT ISNULL(Files.DataCounted, 0), LastTwelveMonth.Date_Value
FROM LastTwelveMonth
LEFT JOIN ValuesForMonth ON ValuesForMonth.DateForData = LastTwelveMonth.Date_Value
```

Comment: I had to change `ISNULL(Files.DataCounted, 0)` to `ISNULL(ValuesForMonth.DataCounted, 0)` and add `option (maxrecursion 0)`. The query hangs. Any help is appreciated.